# SyncFusion ListView in MAUI (IOS Rendering)

Tags: ios, maui, syncfusion

I am populating a List inside a refresh view in MAUI. The Items should have a hidden details when firstly populated. if an item is clicked on the details become visible. When the first 20 Items are populated using API, the details are good. but when I scroll down and get new Items, the details part messes up and shows as if it's empty. I am using Syncfusion Version 22.21.38.
PS.  I have tried it in Grid, but same result.

I tried to make a list with hidden details, when an item is clicked the details should show under it.

```
<RefreshView    IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefresh}"  Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}">
    <syncfusion:SfListView x:Name="listView2"
                       ItemsSource="{Binding Jobs}"
    LoadMorePosition="End" LoadMoreOption="AutoOnScroll" LoadMoreCommand="{Binding LoadMoreCommand}" LoadMoreCommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference listView2}}"> 
        <syncfusion:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate> 
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                <StackLayout BackgroundColor="{Binding ListColor}">
                 <Label Text="{Binding AssetName}"   Style="{StaticResource JobMonitorLabelStyle}"/>
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout x:Name="DetailsGrid" IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}" >
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Text="{x:Static resx:AppTexts.lblAsset}"  Style="{StaticResource JobMonitorDetailLabelStyle}"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Asset}"  Style="{StaticResource JobMonitorDetailLabelStyle}" LineBreakMode="CharacterWrap"/>
                            </StackLayout> 
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Text="{x:Static resx:AppTexts.lblParent}" Style="{StaticResource JobMonitorDetailLabelStyle}" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding Parent}"   Style="{StaticResource JobMonitorDetailLabelStyle}"  LineBreakMode="CharacterWrap"/>
                            </StackLayout> 
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Text="{x:Static resx:AppTexts.lblRequestedBy}" Style="{StaticResource JobMonitorDetailLabelStyle}" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding RequestedBy}"  Style="{StaticResource JobMonitorDetailLabelStyle}"  LineBreakMode="CharacterWrap" />
                            </StackLayout>

                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Text="{x:Static resx:AppTexts.lblStart}"  Style="{StaticResource JobMonitorDetailLabelStyle}"  />
                                <Label Text="{Binding Start}"  Style="{StaticResource JobMonitorDetailLabelStyle}"  LineBreakMode="CharacterWrap"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                                 
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Text="{x:Static resx:AppTexts.lblRequired}"   Style="{StaticResource JobMonitorDetailLabelStyle}"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Required}" Style="{StaticResource JobMonitorDetailLabelStyle}"  LineBreakMode="CharacterWrap"/>
                            </StackLayout> 
                            <StackLayout    Orientation="Horizontal"> 
                                <Label Text="{x:Static resx:AppTexts.lblWorkType}"  Style="{StaticResource JobMonitorDetailLabelStyle}" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding WorkType}"   Style="{StaticResource JobMonitorDetailLabelStyle}"   LineBreakMode="CharacterWrap"/>
                                <Label Text="{x:Static resx:AppTexts.lblPriority}"  Style="{StaticResource JobMonitorDetailLabelStyle}" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding Priority}"  Style="{StaticResource JobMonitorDetailLabelStyle}"  LineBreakMode="CharacterWrap" />
                            </StackLayout>

                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </syncfusion:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
    </syncfusion:SfListView>
   </RefreshView>
```

Comment: did you mean to post more than that XAML snippet?